# Would it be possible to port Tor to Musl libc?

Tags: linux

I didn't go through the source code of Tor yet but as far as I know the executable doesn't work on Musl out of the box. The executable basically does nothing when I open it.
I did see that Tor itself was written in C and objective C for the biggest part so it's most likely going to be heavily dependent on Glibc.
If anybody knows if porting Tor to Musl libc is a "possible goal" to accomplish, please let me know.

Comment: I know that people have tried it, and I'm not sure if any were successful. Hopefully someone posts here, but if not, keep looking/asking around and you might find one of the projects that tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible for sure, moreover - it's been ported already.
Alpine Linux has a port/package of Tor and is built around musl libc and busybox.
ProofLink: https://build.alpinelinux.org/buildlogs/build-edge-x86_64/community/tor/tor-0.4.3.6-r0.log

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out when I have a new LFS system that runs Musl. How do I use an APKBUILD?